# How to make celeryd as daemon in Linux centos for django

Tags: python, django, linux, celery

I am following [this tutorial](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/cookbook/daemonizing.html#daemonizing) and i have made the file `celeryd` in `/etc/default` directory

Now , i am try `/etc/init.d/celeryd start` and its not working.

ERROR : file not found

They have not written anything more on that page. what should i do

```
1) which file i need to put in /etc/default/celeryd 
2) My celeryd bin file is in /opt/python2.7/bin/celeryd
```

Comment: what is not working? please be specific and if there is error thrown, please edit this question with the error.

Answer (score 0):

Did you copy [these files](https://github.com/ask/celery/tree/master/contrib/debian/init.d) to the /etc/init.d/ directory?

Comment: 1) All three files have same content 2) which file i need to put in `/etc/default/celeryd` 3) My `celeryd` bin file is in `/opt/python2.7/bin/celeryd`

Comment: If you want to start a script with /etc/init.d/celeryd start then you have to paste the file https://github.com/ask/celery/blob/master/contrib/generic-init.d/celeryd to the /etc/init.d/ directory. /etc/default/celeryd is only a config file which can look like:  

`CELERYD_NODES=3   

CELERYD_CHDIR="/opt/Myproject/"  

CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300"`

Ehh...I can't get used to the mini-Markdown syntax to paste the code here